# CORS not allowed when Origin includes port number

Tags: node.js, webpack, cors, cross-domain, port

I have an application running on a Node.js server. CORS is enabled but my POST requests are getting denied (`400, not allowed`).

When sending the same requests using POSTMAN, I can get it to work by simply removing the port number from the `Origin`. But it should work correctly, as both the ports from the request and the origin are one and the same.

e.g. This doesn't work:

```
# Request
Request URL: http://the_address:the_port/etc
Request Method: POST

# Headers
Origin: http://the_address:the_port
```

While this works perfectly fine:

```
# Headers
Origin: http://the_address
```

Would you have an idea why this could break? Shouldn't CORS allow same origin requests even when a port is in the Origin, as long as it's the same port?

PS: I'm also using webpack and React, but I don't think it's related (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: You can’t manually change the `Origin` header that the browser sends, right? The browser sets the  `Origin` header it sends based on what it knows to be the actual origin of the frontend JavaScript code you’re sending the request from. So if the origin of the URL your code is sending  sending the request to isn’t exactly the same as the value of the `Origin` header the browser sends, then the browser considers that a cross-origin request.

Comment: The only way you can change the actual origin for your frontend JavaScript code to `http://the_address` from `http://the_address:the_port` is to actually serve your frontend JavaScript code from `http://the_address`, which has port 80 as its port number, instead of from `http://the_address:the_port`, which has something other than port 80 as its port number.

Comment: show us the full CORS error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t manually change the `Origin` header the browser sends. The browser sets the `Origin` header it sends based on what it knows to be the actual origin of the frontend JavaScript code you’re sending the request from. So if the origin of the URL your code’s sending the request to isn’t exactly the same as the value of the `Origin` header the browser sends, then the browser considers that a cross-origin request.

The only way to change the actual origin for your frontend code to `http://the_address` from `http://the_address:the_port` is to actually serve the code from `http://the_address`, which has 80 as its port, instead of from `http://the_address:the_port`, which has something other than 80 as its port number.